# NSNumber objCType EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber

i am now facing a case that caused by objCType of NSNumber, which is numberWithInt.
When i retrieve it from NSUserDefault, and check it type. EXC_BAD_ACCESS fired.

Here is the code:

```
 NSNumber* number = [uD objectForKey:@"some_key"]；
 NSLog(@"Data Type %@",[number objCType]);//This Line fired EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

uD stand for the UserDefault Object Initialized in the other part of the code.
This issue doesn't exists when NSNumber is created from numberWithLong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objCType` returns a C String, so you need to use `%s` in your format string and not `%@`. Like this:

```
NSLog(@"Data Type %s", [number objCType]);
```

Note that you might want to guard against `nil` values of `number` by doing something like:

```
NSLog(@"Data Type %s", [number objCType] ?: "");
```

Comment: Thanks，i will wrap it with NSString, due to the design issue.

Comment: @FrankFung: Your comment makes absolutely no sense. I can't imagine any sensible reason to convert the result of objCType to an NSString.

Comment: That is because i have a constant message string, that will handle both NSString and C String. Wouldn't wrap it as NSString would be a better case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a c type with %@ on NSLog. You should do this to check the type.

```
if (strcmp([number objCType], @encode(BOOL)) == 0) {
    NSLog(@"this is a bool");
} else if (strcmp([number objCType], @encode(int)) == 0) {
    NSLog(@"this is an int");
}
```

Comment: Ok, then you should check if number is nil, maybe yo haven't on the user defaults at this point.

Comment: yup, i have a custom built class for handling the userDefault, nil is already checked, only the remaining case.
Besides, NSNumber will never return objCType of int when retrieving from NSUserDefault, in both case of NSNumber is declared on numberWithInt and numberWithInteger.
Thanks for your help again.